# Fetch ActiveRecord query result as an array of hashes with chosen attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, activerecord, hash

The model `User` has `first`, `last` and `login` as attributes. It also has a method called `name` that joins `first` and `last`.

What I want is to iterate through the `Users` records and create an array of hashes with the attributes I want. Like so:

```
results = []
User.all.map do |user|
    record = {}
    record["login"] = user.login
    record["name"] = user.name
    results << record
end
```

Is there a cleaner way in Ruby to do this?

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? (MySQL, Postgres)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would write:

```
results = User.all.map { |u| { login: u.login, name: u.name } }
```

Comment: Thank you! I did `users.map { |u| { "login" => u.login, "name" => u.name } }` because I needed the keys to be strings and not symbols.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`ActiveRecord::QueryMethods#select`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-select) and [`ActiveRecord::Relation#as_json`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Relation/as_json):

```
User.select(:login, '(first || last) as name').as_json(except: :id)
```

Comment: This cool, but create one big hash, which useless for records creation. Also select returns `ActiveRecord_Relation` and to_hash method raise an erorr.

Comment: @Зелёный: it was kinda the point, or am I missing something? Together with your assumption of record creation, I guess..

Comment: `User.select(:id, :name).map(&:attributes)` here is works code.

Comment: This code shouldn't work. Could you add the output of `User.select(:login, :name).class` ?

Comment: @Зелёный: My bad, I was sure I was talking about `as_json` method.

Answer (score 3):

Trying to map over `User.all` is going to cause performance issues (later, if not now). To avoid instantiating all User objects, you can use `pluck` to get the data directly out of the DB and then map it.

```
results = User.all.pluck(:login, :first, :last).map do |login, first, last|
  { 'login' => login, 'name' => first << last }
end
```

Instantiating all the users is going to be problematic. Even the `as_json` relation method is going to do that. It may even be a problem using this method, depending on how many users there are.

Also, this assumes that `User#name` really just does `first + last`. If it's different, you can change the logic in the block.

Comment: Yes, I actually don't use `User.all`, its the result of a specific query, I put User.all in the question just to simplify since what matter is the return: records of the user model. Your answer is correct also, but @spickermann answered first. +1 and thank you!

Comment: No problem, just make sure to be aware of the performance impact if it's a large query :)

Comment: It's a specific query for autocomplete purposes, in the worst case it'll return a couple dozen results.

Answer (score 0):

The poorly named and poorly documented method `ActiveRecord::Result#to_hash` does what you want, I think.

```
User.select(:login, :name).to_hash
```

Poorly named because it does in fact return an array of Hash, which seems pretty poor form for a method named `to_hash`.

Comment: `to_hash` is for a result set, which is what is returned when executing a raw query, not for a relation

Comment: Also, name is not an attribute, is a method that returns a string.